# Zend FetchAll returns Schema

Tags: php, zend-framework, fetch

I run the following code and I get back a pretty involved object back. I'm just looking for the data.

```
Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
            $Table = new Zend_Db_Table('host');
        $data = $Table->fetchAll(); 
        var_dump($data);
```

The object comes back like so, which is difficult at best to parse. I know it supposed to be an object, but I thought fetchAll was just a query. What am I doing wrong?

```
object(Zend_Db_Table_Rowset)#40 (10) {
  ["_data":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_table":protected]=>
  object(Zend_Db_Table)#23 (18) {
    ["_definition":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["_definitionConfigName":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["_db":protected]=>
    object(Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql)#5 (12) {
      ["_pdoType":protected]=>
      string(5) "mysql"
      ["_numericDataTypes":protected]=>
      array(16) {
        [0]=>
        int(0)
        [1]=>
        int(1)
        [2]=>
        int(2)
        ["INT"]=>
        int(0)
        ["INTEGER"]=>
        int(0)
        ["MEDIUMINT"]=>
        int(0)
        ["SMALLINT"]=>
        int(0)
        ["TINYINT"]=>
        int(0)
        ["BIGINT"]=>
        int(1)
        ["SERIAL"]=>
        int(1)
        ["DEC"]=>
        int(2)
        ["DECIMAL"]=>
        int(2)
        ["DOUBLE"]=>
        int(2)
        ["DOUBLE PRECISION"]=>
        int(2)
        ["FIXED"]=>
        int(2)
        ["FLOAT"]=>
        int(2)
      }
      ["_defaultStmtClass":protected]=>
      string(21) "Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo"
      ["_config":protected]=>
      array(8) {
        ["host"]=>
        string(9) "localhost"
        ["username"]=>
        string(4) "root"
        ["password"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["dbname"]=>
        string(5) "mysql"
        ["charset"]=>
        NULL
        ["persistent"]=>
        bool(false)
        ["options"]=>
        array(3) {
          ["caseFolding"]=>
          int(0)
          ["autoQuoteIdentifiers"]=>
          bool(true)
          ["fetchMode"]=>
          int(2)
        }
        ["driver_options"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
      ["_fetchMode":protected]=>
      int(2)
      ["_profiler":protected]=>
      object(Zend_Db_Profiler)#4 (4) {
        ["_queryProfiles":protected]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["_enabled":protected]=>
        bool(false)
        ["_filterElapsedSecs":protected]=>
        NULL
        ["_filterTypes":protected]=>
        NULL
      }
      ["_defaultProfilerClass":protected]=>
      string(16) "Zend_Db_Profiler"
      ["_connection":protected]=>
      object(PDO)#25 (0) {
      }
      ["_caseFolding":protected]=>
      int(0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this to degub:

```
$Table->fetchAll()->toArray();
```

Comment: perfect, but why did this work and without toArray(), pulls in the schema definition for this table? I dont see that in the docs?

Comment: because, by default, or Zend_Db Doctrinte, return the result set format stantard object, I believe that a better solution for them internally! Please set my answer as accept! Thanks